# Why am I seeing "This application does not support this device's CPU type"?

Tags: iphone, ios

When trying to build and install an application on an iPod running iOS 4.2.1, I'm seeing the error

> This application does not support this device's CPU type

I'm trying to build the application using xcode 4.3, as well as xcode 4.4, and still seeing this. What can cause this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 27):

I have encountered such a problem today on **iOS 11.2.1** with **iPhone 7** devices.
The reason is that the previous project set up a 32-bit architecture that is no longer supported.
And I solved the problem as follows：

**Project -> Build Settings -> Architectures value should be set `Standard architectures - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)`**

[image]

Answer (score 15):

From the project build settings -> Architectures, make sure you have both `armv6` and `armv7` values.

Also, you can check your Info.plist file, under `Required device capabilities`. If there's `armv7` there, remove it.

Comment: Another configuration setting you should check is "Build Active Architecture Only" in Build Settings. That should be NO at least for the Release.

Comment: Thank you masam- I had another team who kept writing this, and it was causing me countless hours of lost sleep.

Comment: I used iPhone 5s 11.1.2(15c153) and I want to build my project using Xcode 9.2(iOS 11.2) and also try Xcode 9.1(iOS 11.1). But app installation failed continuously. It is only for cocos2d v2.x project.  Alert! "App installation failed, This application does not support this device’s CPU type."

Answer (score 10):

If you are getting this error building Unity 3D application, change scripting backend to IL2CPP, and select "Universal" architecture.

[image: ios player setting configuration]

Comment: This helped me out too! Thank you!

Comment: from where we will get this settings??

Answer (score 0):

This post led me to my answer.  Thanks @adig and @masam

I have an iOS 8.4 enterprise signed app that would only work on certain device types when I tried to install it from our internal app store, and it was inconsistent.  I wasn't getting any helpful error messages, even from the device console, until I tried to deploy it using the XCode Devices to a 5th gen iPod.  It said "This application does not support this device type" which led me to here.  I was debugging on a 6th gen iPod/iPhone 6.

I was archiving from a different scheme than I usually release from and I was only building the current architecture which meant that it would only work on a certain type of device depending on what was plugged in when I archived.

So make sure that "build active architecture only" is NO when you are archiving an app to sign as an Enterprise app.