# Got "This application does not support this device's CPU type" trying to run my application on iPhone 4S from Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, architecture, cpu

The application is built for armv7 architecture. I double checked binary header, and it contains 12 for CPU type and 9 for CPU subtype.

The application runs well on iPhone 5 but fails on iPhone 4S or iPad Mini. Both have iOS 7.0.3 installed. Xcode version 5.0. There are no specific processor requirements in plist.

See device console log below. Any ideas?

```
Nov 14 13:09:42 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: 0x25d000 file_matches_my_arch: Can't map input file: /var/tmp/install_staging.7IZ38C/xxxx.app/xxxx

Nov 14 13:09:42 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: 0x25d000 do_preflight_verification: Incorrect architecture at /var/tmp/install_staging.7IZ38C/xxxx.app

Nov 14 13:09:42 iPhone-4S mobile_installation_proxy[138] <Error>: 0x181000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1

Nov 14 13:09:42 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: 0x25d000 install_application: Could not preflight application install

Nov 14 13:09:42 iPhone-4S mobile_installation_proxy[138] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil

Nov 14 13:09:42 iPhone-4S mobile_installation_proxy[138] <Error>: 0x181000 handle_install: Installation failed: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x15d3fc90 {Error=IncorrectArchitecture}

Nov 14 13:09:42 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: 0x25d000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Xcode 5 but in Xcode 4 you have to make sure you have `armv6` set as well.

See: 
[Why am I seeing "This application does not support this device's CPU type"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670006/why-am-i-seeing-this-application-does-not-support-this-devices-cpu-type)

Comment: I never had to have armv6 architecture in order to run on armv7 device.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the ipa (Xcode 6, same build configuration) solved this problem for me. Seems like a bug within the build process to me.