# Unable to download application in device with ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, installation, ios11, ad-hoc-distribution

I have build my application two years ago but not submitted on App Store. Now I want to submit the app on App store. But when I try to install app using Xcode or through diawi link of its Ad hoc build, app is not installing on device.

When I try to install app through Xcode, sometimes it shows

> this application does not support this device's cpu type

and sometimes

> Could not write to the device

and when I try to install app through diawi link of its Ad hoc build, it shows

> Unable to download application, `<app-name>` could not be installed at this time

This issue is only occurring in device with ios 11. I have checked my certificates as well as UDID of device in which i am trying to install. Also I have set Architectures of Build Setting of Xcode to Standard architectures (arm7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD).  It is completely working fine in device with iOS version below 11.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670006/why-am-i-seeing-this-application-does-not-support-this-devices-cpu-type

Comment: @Rushabh It is not working.

Comment: Do you have `armv7 armv7s arm64` as Valid Architectures in your Build Settings? For Projects and Targets? Also make sure to always select "Generic iOS Device" when you archive your app, otherwhise Xcode will build the app for the selected devices architecture only.

Comment: @Pascal_AC Yes I have armv7 armv7s arm64 all of three in my Valid Architectures of Build Settings. And even app is not installing through Xcode also.

Comment: Which XCode version you are using ??

Comment: @SagarMahajan I have tried with Xcode 8.3.2 and Xcode 9 both.

Comment: Few days ago I have same problem with unity project, I solved it by updating xcode9.1.  if it is Unity project than I can help you otherwise you can add screenshots of xcode for better idea.

Comment: exactly im also facing this issue from past so many days and i already notified the diawi team  but they said to check the provisional profiles but everything is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have find the solution of my issue. In my case I have to remove some old libraries which is not supporting in ios 11 and have to change some deprecated code.

If your code is deprecated or some libraries are stop working then Xcode will show you only error of

> this application does not support this device's cpu type

or

> Could not write to the device

So you have to check that which library is deprecated after launching of ios 11.

Also you have to check all other details like Build Active Architectures Only, Architectures, Valid Architectures, Required device capabilities from Info.plist.