# Why this alert? "App installation failed, This application does not support this device’s CPU type"

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I used iPhone 5s 11.1.2(15c153) and I want to build my project using Xcode 9.2(iOS 11.2) and also try Xcode 9.1(iOS 11.1). But app installation failed continuously. It is only for cocos2d v2.x project. Please anyone help me in this circumstances.

Alert!

App installation failed 
This application does not support this device’s CPU type.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: cocos2dx with box2d project

Comment: do you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670006/why-am-i-seeing-this-application-does-not-support-this-devices-cpu-type

Comment: I have checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670006/why-am-i-seeing-this-application-does-not-support-this-devices-cpu-type